# SharePoint 2013 Apps Monitor

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-addin, app, logging, monitoring

I am using SharePoint 2013 Server. 
 I am monitoring an app, I followed this guide: [Monitor apps for SharePoint](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj219567%28v=office.15%29.aspx).
In the monitor, I can see that the errors are updated each 24 hours and the history logs is only for the last 4 days.
Is it possible to change these value? 
I would like to update the log more often.

Thanks, Nk

Answer (score 0):

According to MSFT Usage is Once a Day, this why you seeing once a day, but for the app errors those process more often. here MSFT office statement from technet you mentioned.

"The app usage and app error details data that is in the app monitoring pages can be delayed for up to 29 hours. The app details depend on when the ECM analytics timer job is scheduled to run. When the timer job runs, it collects events for the previous day. For example, if the timer job is scheduled to run at 5 A.M., then the most recent events that are collected are from 11:59 P.M. the previous day. An event that occurs at 12:01 A.M. will not appear in the app details pages until up to 29 hours later."

&

"Be aware that in the Monitored Apps page, the error dialog box can show more errors than are counted. The errors are counted every 24 hours, but the error messages are processed more often. As a result, the error dialog box can show error messages that are generated in the current day before the count is updated at the end of the day."

Questions? How long since you enable the Usage logging and configure the APP monitor?

Comment: Thanks, I read that but I thought that there was a way to change these settings. I have to wait till 29 hours to see my apps log, where is the point!?

Comment: if you change your Usage and Health Data scheudle it will automatically change, but never advised. i could not get what you ask for 29 hours? MSFT said, if a your timer jobs run daily at 5 then it will process the entries till 11:59 and after that cut off time all entries will be process next day at 5...which make it 29 hours.